# python pyqt4 combobox 

Tags: python, pyqt

I am working with python plugins.I designed my form using pyqt4 designer.It has one combobox.
I coded in python as follows:

```
self.db._exec_sql(c, "SELECT  "+column_name1+" from  "+table_name+" ")

    for row in c.fetchall():
             print row
             self.comboBox.addItem(row)
```

**row** gives me all the values of specific column of specific table. I am listing all column values from database into combobox.But  **self.comboBox.addItem(row)**  gives error saying :

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
 QComboBox.addItem(QString, QVariant userData=QVariant()): argument 1 has unexp
ected type 'tuple'


 QComboBox.addItem(QIcon, QString, QVariant userData=QVariant()): argument 1 ha
s unexpected type 'tuple'
```

How do i list values in combobox??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fetchall()` method yields tuples, even when you select only one value in the SQL `SELECT` clause. Change your code to:

```
for row in c.fetchall():
    self.comboBox.addItem(row[0])
```

Comment: yes it works:) but only values of datatype character varying are added to combobox..not values of datatype integer..help me out..

Comment: addItem only accepts `str` or `unicode` arguments. If you have an `int`, you may cast it to `unicode`, like this: `self.comboBox.addItem(unicode(row[0]))`.